# after updating to api level 26 I get: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getScaledHorizontalScrollFactor

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to update my app to use api level 26 and now I'm getting a very painful error when trying to start up the app. Here is the exception that seems to be causing it:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getScaledHorizontalScrollFactor(Landroid/view/ViewConfiguration;Landroid/content/Context;)F in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewConfigurationCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompat' appears in /data/app/com.sprayme.teamrsm.analyticspraydown-2/base.apk)
```

My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sprayme.teamrsm.analyticspraydown"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.2"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

If I set my compile and target versions back to 25 and the compile items back from 26.0.2 to 25.1.3 like I had them before, everything runs again.

I have searched high and low and haven't found anything that's helped yet. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewere in your classes or libraries you use the getScaledHorizontalScrollFactor method. This method is in the ViewConfigurationCompat class. According to Google, this class is deprecated in api 26. You have to use ViewConfiguration directly.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewConfigurationCompat.html